# Array Sort and Index Largest Value to Smallest Google Sheet

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have database in data google sheet and it has four columns as below:

[image]

In column T (Frequency After Sort), I want to sort from largest value to smallest. I use formula and it worked. The formula in below:

```
=IFERROR(LARGE($R$2:$R; ROW(1:1)); "")
```

But i got problem, i did not found formula how to index column S (Key Sheet After Sort) to column Q based on column T. Before that i created formula and it not worked. The formula in below:

```
=INDEX($Q$2:$Q; MATCH(T2; $R$2:$R; 0))
```

[image]

Can somebody help me with this please? Especially in the column S. Later, i will use column S and T to make Pareto Chart. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SORT()` function instead without having that extra column created by `LARGE()` function. Try-

```
=SORT(R2:S,1,0)
```

Comment: Sorry sir, i did not understand. What column is this formula =SORT(R2:S,1,0) applied to?

Comment: @AkhmadFahrudhin Put it to `T2` cell.

Comment: the output is error sir

Comment: Sorry sir, It seems, you misunderstood. In column T is the correct formula. I just this ask about column S, how to index column Q to column S based on value column T

Comment: @AkhmadFahrudhin Did you try it? This will do same thing what you are trying to achieve by two different formula. Put this `=SORT(Q2:R,2,0)` formula to `S2` cell.

Comment: okey sir, it worked, thank you so much

Comment: @AkhmadFahrudhin Glad to know. If it helps then please consider accepting the answer (tick mark it as green).